# Creating IIS Manager User for giving access to IIS Remote Management

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis, windows-server-2016

I am enabling IIS Remote Management Service, and for that I want to use IIS Manager credentials. However, I am not sure how to create one.

I am on Windows Server 2016. How would I do that?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/management/authentication/credentials/add#how-to-add-iis-manager-user-credentials-to-a-server

Comment: this helped, can you pls answer this question